# Anti-aliasing text in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a WinForms form, and would like to make it so that all text (e.g. labels, buttons) is anti-aliased.  This is driving me crazy because I can't find anything on google, which either means it's so obvious or I'm way off-base.

My best idea has been to override OnPaint in my main form, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because what you did only affects text drawn directly on the form. I guess you would have to override OnPaint in user controls subclassing labels, buttons, etc.

Comment: I guess I just assumed that after painting itself, the Form would pass the same Graphics instance on to its sub-controls to paint themselves with, and so by setting the TextRenderingHint before anything gets painted, it would carry through.  But basically you're saying that each control is painted with its own Graphics instance, so there is no way to do this globally, short of subclassing every control I use?

Comment: Pretty sure the form and contained controls don't share the same graphics context.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't want anti-aliasing so much as sub-pixel rendering which is used by ClearType. More specifically you may want to check out the [TextRenderingHint Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssazt6bs.aspx) member ClearTypeGridFit.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, anti-aliasing only works when calling `DrawString` on the `Graphics` object, after you set the anti-aliasing mode as you described in your answer.

Standard WinForms controls don't use this method, so a simple override won't work.

Comment: Actually, overriding OnPaint like hvjackson did for the form but for a user control subclassing the Button class has some effects.

Comment: All depends on how the control draws itself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but as some people are still using WinForms (including myself) but I thought I'd add a useful bit of information here.

Setting Graphics.CompositingQuality to HighQuality in addition to TextRenderingHint to AntiAlias has a significant impact on the quality of anti-aliased text in WinForms. I have at least used this trick to produce custom high-quality Labels and other form controls. I find that without it, the quality that WinForms produces is not really up to scratch for modern UIs, and the result was significantly poorer quality than my mockups in Photoshot/Designer. With this set the text appears much smoother and crisper.

An example of how I'd implement this on a Label:

```
public class AntiAliasingLabel : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), 0, 0);
    }
}
```